# Adding additional html list elements using JSON and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I can currently add a `<li>` element to my webpage using Javascript with information from a JSON file.

However, when I try and add another `<li>` element underneath the first one using the same methods it replaces the first one instead of adding it below the first one.

How do I get it to add another instead of replacing it?

Here is my Javascript code:

```
$('#links').html('<li>' + jsonObj.pageText[5].ref1 + '</li>')
$('#links').html('<li>' + jsonObj.pageText[5].ref2 + '</li>')
```

ref2 replaces the first one.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0hxc8a5q/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **append** or **preppend** instead of **html**

Answer (score 0):

The .html(...) command replaces the html, so you would need to:

```
$('#links').html('<li>' + jsonObj.pageText[5].ref1+'</li>')
$('#links').html($('#links').html() + '<li>' + jsonObj.pageText[5].ref2+'</li>')
```

...or:

```
$('#links').append($('<li>').html(jsonObj.pageText[5].ref1))
$('#links').append($('<li>').html(jsonObj.pageText[5].ref2))
```